# Schema Name Attribute Is Not Working .Net Core 6.0

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-6.0

I have migrated .net core 2.2 to 6.0

on backend using mysql db.

**I have installed these packages:-**

- Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore 6.0.0
- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 6.0.0
- MySqlConnector 2.0.0
- Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql 6.0.0

now I'm facing runtime schema name issue,
on server I have multiple databases,
it is getting the schema name from connection string name which is **"testDb"** and override the the schema name I have define on entity like

```cs
[Table("mytable", Schema = "devDb")]
public class Mytable
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

I have also tried with fluent api but not working

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity<MyTable>(e => { e.ToTable("myTable", "devDb"); });
```

**Startup.cs**

```cs
var defaultConnection = Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");           
services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => options.UseMySql(defaultConnection, ServerVersion.AutoDetect(defaultConnection)));
```

**context**

```cs
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<User>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(string connectionString) : base(connectionString) { }

    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options) : base(options)
    {
        Database.SetCommandTimeout(100000000);
    }
  
  public MyTable MyTable {get;set;} //it is just an example
}
```

**Exception**
**MySqlException:** Table 'testDb.myTable' doesn't exist

**the table exist in devDb**

Comment: Side note: setting command timeout to (virtually) infinitive is not a sensible thing to do. Choose a reasonable value (or take the default) and set a custom timeout for exceptional cases.

Comment: *it is getting the schema name from connection string name* -- So how do you tell EF which schema it should use?

Comment: @GertArnold as its mention on top entity [Table("mytable", Schema = "devDb")]  but it takes schema from connection string

Comment: What I means is that AFAIK there's no schema entry in a connection string (is there in MySql?). So how do you tell EF that it should use "testDb" as default schema?

Comment: @GertArnold Server=xxxxxx; Port=3306; Database=test; Uid=root; Pwd=xxxx"
here Database

Comment: @GertArnold above mention is connection string

Comment: No "testDb" there. You must have mapping code in the context that sets the default schema. It's very likely that this overrides the schema in attributes.

Comment: testDB or test i mention here are just a dummy names of database, as you see in exception testDb.myTable doesn't exist testDb is already mapped i want to map this specific table with **devDB**  for which i use this attribute [Table("mytable", Schema = "devDb")] but it still mapping with testDb

Comment: @GertArnold I have also tried fluent api 
``` 
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
            modelBuilder.Entity<MyTable>(e => { e.ToTable("myTable", "devDb"); });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

MySQL doesn't do "schemas" in the sense that other database systems do.

A "schema" in MySQL is what others call a "database".

The [default behavior for Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore](https://github.com/PomeloFoundation/Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql/blob/27f227388a5e1b68292f6c649227bdf0637598d7/src/EFCore.MySql/Infrastructure/MySqlSchemaBehavior.cs#L14) would be to throw an exception whenever it encounters a configured schema somewhere.

Comment: well it is working in asp.net core 2.2 after migration to 6.0 it is not mapping schema

Comment: I sincerely doubt that, as MySQL has never supported schemas.